# what to delete after assignment?

Tags: c++

If I have:

```
template<>
char *toBytes<uint64_t>(uint64_t src) {
  char *data = new char[8];
  //...stuff
  return data;
}

template<>
void write<uint64_t>(char *dst, uint64_t src) {
  char *srcBytes = toBytes(src);
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    *(dst++) = *(srcBytes++); //am I leaking here?
  }
}
```

that gets called with something like:

```
char *keyPtr = new char[27];
//...stuff
write(keyPtr, 1234ull);
//...write up to 27
```

If do `delete[] keyPtr;` would I have deleted srcBytes? I think the question is, on the line asking if I'm leaking, is that doing a copy and as a result deleting `keyPtr` leaves `srcBytes` still to be deleted?

Still learning C++ and it's not always clear to me when the copy constructor is called vs the assignment operator.

**EDIT 1**:

Fixed delete as per @Steephen's answer

**EDIT 2**

Add toBytes as per @WhozCraig's comment

Comment: No, deleting `keyPtr` has nothing to do with managing the memory referred by `srcBytes`. And since we cannot see how that memory originated (the source for `toBytes` is not included in your question), we cannot say whether deleting `srcBytes` is needed or not. If it is dynamically allocated, it needs deleting, but note you will lose the initial address of the allocation with that loop construct that continually increments `srcBytes`, so you'll need to save a pointer to it off to `delete[]` it, or use a different loop mechanic.

Comment: With your addition, you definitely need to delete that returned buffer from `toBytes()`. The problem is, the only pointer that refers to it is modified immediately after it is assigned. I.e. you lose the pointer you need to `delete []`. May want to think about that.

Comment: As a side note, as your learn more and more about C++ and other languages, one design problems starts coming into play in terms of managing the lifecycle and conveying ownership of dynamic memory in general. Different methodologies get employed including memory pools (commonly used w/ Objective C), or shared pointers (found in things like the boost library). It helps conveying the notion to users of an API that this memory is being managed, although with some performance costs (ie. reference counters, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a memory leak. No, `delete []`-ing `keyPtr`has nothing to do with `srcBytes`, an independent allocation. The two addressed buffers are unrelated (except for *content* due to your copy-code).

Apart from the obvious (using `std::vector<>` and letting [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) take over the memory management for all of this), a fairly minimal change to your code to plug the leak would loop something like this:

```
template<>
void write<uint64_t>(char *dst, uint64_t src) 
{
    char *srcBytes = toBytes(src);
    std::copy(srcBytes, srcBytes+8, dst);
    delete [] srcBytes;
}
```

or using a smart pointer:

```
template<>
void write<uint64_t>(char *dst, uint64_t src) 
{
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> srcBytes(toBytes(src));
    std::copy(srcBytes.get(), srcBytes.get()+8, dst);
}
```

Both use the `std::copy` stock algorithm which both accomplishes what you seem to want, while retaining the original result of `toBytes` for proper cleanup. Which you choose (or perhaps something entirely different still) I leave to you.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use

```
delete [] keyPtr;
```

instead of calling `delete` over for loop;

If you allocate memory using `new[]`, you should use `delete []`, and if you use `new`, you should use `delete`. In your case you are using the former one.

> I think the question is, on the line asking if I'm leaking, is that
>   doing a copy and as a result deleting keyPtr leaves srcBytes

If your program allocated memory for `srcBytes` using new operator you should delete it it as same way you do for `keyPtr` . Because resource handling by both pointers are independent even after your assignment in your case.

Answer (score 1):

These are a few cases where you will leak the memory where you used "new":

- The function runs out of scope before you could delete it and there is no pointer to the allocated memory outside of the function.
- You forget to delete where appropriate
- You mix `delete` and `delete []`
- Exception is caught between the use of "new" and "delete".

Even as a beginner, it's a good idea to get familiar with smart pointers.